# How to base64 encode inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation, base64

I am trying to implement a simple script on a site that will return base64 encoded information from google's ajax API.  This is what I am playing with so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA0duujonFsEX871htGWZBHRS76H0qhS7Lb-D1Gd0Mnaiuid8Z7BQIyz2kMpojKizoyiCQA4yRkKAKug" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var location = 'Unable to determine your location.';
    if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
      var loc = google.loader.ClientLocation;
      location = 'Country: <strong>' + loc.address.country + '</strong>, Region: <strong>' + loc.address.region + '</strong>, City: <strong>' +
                 loc.address.city + '</strong>, Lat/Long: <strong>' + loc.latitude + ', ' + loc.longitude + '</strong>';
    }
    jQuery('.geolocation').html(location);
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="geolocation"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

It returns the info I am trying to get properly, but I need to base64 encode the separate parts such as country, region, city, lat and longitude.  In php it would be simple, but I cannot figure out how to do it in javascript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you encode to Base64 using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript)

Answer (score 21):

Mozilla, WebKit and Opera all have [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.btoa) and [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.atob) functions for base 64 encoding and decoding respectively. Use those where possible because they will almost certainly be massively faster than a JavaScript implementation and fall back to one of the many scripts that turn up when you do [a web search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+base64+encode).

**EDIT 10 SEPTEMBER 2013: `atob()` and `btoa()` do not handle Unicode characters outside the ASCII range. MDN has [workarounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_.22Unicode_Problem.22) but I can't vouch for them. Thanks to @larspars for pointing this out.**

For example, if you were using the example from amphetamachine's answer, you could do the following:

```
if (!window.btoa) {
    window.btoa = function(str) {
        return Base64.encode(str);
    }
}

if (!window.atob) {
    window.atob = function(str) {
        return Base64.decode(str);
    }
}

alert( btoa("Some text") );
```

Comment: Note that atob and btoa won't handle unicode, whereas @amphetamachine's answer will. Base64.encode('☃') works, while btoa('☃') throws an error (tested in Firefox, Chrome and Opera)

Comment: Still doubting on whether to use it, but for now I think I will. We don't have strange characters as we're working with the Dutch language. Thanks for posting it out and editing your comment, this helped a lot in deciding! ;)

Answer (score 15):

[This answer](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html) seems to match what you're looking for.

There's also [this one](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) which is more elegant:

```
/**
 *
 *  Base64 encode / decode
 *  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
 *
 **/

var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks promising, but it is a little out of my depth in javascript.  Maybe I can find a way to do all this in php instead

Answer (score 1):

IE 10 & above and all latest browser

Encode String

```
var str = "raj";
var enc = window.btoa(str); // cmFq
```

Decode String

```
var dec = window.atoa('cmFq'); // raj
```

Or else you might have your own function on page. [small blog with references](http://www.asptricks.net/2016/11/javascript-base64-encode-and-decode.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have part of the code from the answer here:

https://scotch.io/quick-tips/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript

and the other part from the answer on this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776796/2655623

and here is the result:

```
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

window.btoa = function(str) {
    return Base64.encode(str);
}

window.atob = function(str) {
    return Base64.decode(str);
}
```

As this keep everything in one place, I won't involve myself with how window.atb / window.btoa act different in various browsers.