# JSON encode/decode base64 encode/decode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, base64

Is there JSON encode/decode base64 encode/decode function in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to base64 encode inside of javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774622/how-to-base64-encode-inside-of-javascript). Searching is hard, apparently. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+base64

Comment: take a look at: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, btoa() and atob() work in some browsers:

```
var enc = btoa("this is some text");
alert(enc);
alert(atob(enc));
```

Comment: `"Some browsers" === "Gecko and WebKit"`

Comment: @Matt Ball. Most languages would refute that :)

Comment: javascript:window.opera && window.btoa && confirm("hi")

Comment: Why window.opera? I eliminated that and it works in Firefox and Chrome. Not sure why IE's tools don't let me test JavaScript in the script console thingy. I'll keep looking.

Comment: For reference its supported in all browsers since IE 10.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=atob-btoa

Answer (score 5):

JSON and base64 are completely independent.

[Here's a JSON stringifier/parser](http://www.json.org/js.html) (and [direct GitHub link](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)).

[Here's a base64 Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript). [Here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774622/how-to-base64-encode-inside-of-javascript).

Answer (score 4):

This might be helpful for you. Using a combination of this project [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js) and Prototype to parse JSON I wrote two function to encode/decode JSON to Base 64. (These functions don't check for not well formatted json)

```js
    function JSONtoBase64(jsonObj) {
        return Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(Crypto.charenc.UTF8.stringToBytes(Object.toJSON(jsonObj)));
    };

    function base64ToJSON(bytes) {
        var jsonString = Crypto.charenc.UTF8.bytesToString(Crypto.util.base64ToBytes(bytes));
        return jsonString.evalJSON();
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

For non-Mozilla browsers, use: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

For Mozilla browsers, use `btoa()` and `atob()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's one built in, but here's the functions for JSON in jquery: (can't post links since I'm new)
jQuery.getJSON
jQuery.parseJSON

and here's a link for base64 encoding in javascript.
http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON has been added in 1.4 and does not work in previous versions.