# batch convert images to binary strings

Tags: image, encoding, binary, adobe, extendscript

I'm trying to batch convert images to binary strings for use in Adobe ExtendScript Panels. The result I'm want to get is a String that looks like this:

```
\u0089PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x00\x00\x00\x0F\b\x06\x00\x00\x00;\u00D6\u0095J\x00\x00\x00IIDAT(\u0091c`\x18~ --\u00ED?\x0E\u00BC\u009F\x18\u00CD\r8p\x026\u00C5\x06@\u00EC@\x046 \u00C5\u0099\u0084\u009D\r\x14,\u00C0\u00E3T\u00FC\u00CE&\u00C1\x10\u00BC\u009AIw6\u0092f\u00D2\x02\f\u00E4\x14\"\u00FD\u008B\u00E9l\u0090S(\nm\u00BA\x02\x00\u009Dp\u00B2N\u00F1d\x1D\u00FD\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\u00AEB`\u0082
```

But my code generates this:

```
c289 504e 470d 1a0d 0000 000d 4948 4452
0000 000f 0000 000f 0806 0000 003b c396
c295 4a00 0000 4949 4441 5428 c291 6360
187e 202d 2dc3 ad3f 0ec2 bcc2 9f18 c38d
0d38 7002 36c3 8506 40c3 ac40 0436 20c3
85c2 99c2 84c2 9d0d 142c c380 c3a3 54c3
bcc3 8e26 c381 10c2 bcc2 9a49 7736 c292
66c3 9202 0cc3 a414 22c3 bdc2 8bc3 a96c
c290 5328 0d6d c2ba 0200 c29d 70c2 b24e
c3b1 641d c3bd 0000 0000 4945 4e44 c2ae
4260 c282
```

What do I have to do to get soemthing like the first string? This is my code (adobe extendscript). If somebody has a solution in a different language I would also take it.

```
var allImages = loadFiles("*.png");// load files is my own function

if(allImages == null) return;
var folder = allImages[0].parent;
for(var i = 0; i < allImages.length;i++){
        var curfile = File (allImages[i]);

        curfile.open ('r');
        curfile.encoding = 'BINARY';
        var str = curfile.read();
        curfile.close();

        var newfile = new File (folder.fsName + '/' + curfile.name + '.txt');
        newfile.open('w');
        newfile.encoding = 'UTF-8';
        newfile.write(str);
        newfile.close();
    } // end loop i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to write the file content toSource().

```
var allImages = loadFiles("*.png");// load files is my own function

if(allImages == null) return;
var folder = allImages[0].parent;
for(var i = 0; i < allImages.length;i++){
    var curfile = File (allImages[i]);

    curfile.open ('r');
    curfile.encoding = 'BINARY';
    var str = curfile.read();
    curfile.close();

    var newfile = new File (folder.fsName + '/' + curfile.name + '.txt');
    newfile.open('w');
    newfile.encoding = 'UTF-8';
    newfile.write(str.Source()); // <-- Thats the trick
    newfile.close();
} // end loop i
```

### This will result in a file with this content.

```
(new String("\u0089PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x1E\x00\x00\x00\x19\b\x06\x00\x00\x00&5\u009E\x1A\x00\x00\x00\u008DIDATx\u00DA\u00ED\u00D2\u00BB\r\u00C0 \fE\u00D1\f\u00C9\x00\u00B4H\u00F44\x14)\u00A0\u00A0\u00A1c\x00f`@Go\x01>r$+\u0091\u008B\u00DB\u00D9\x1C\u00C5\u00CA\u00E5\u009C\u00BB%\x02L\x12)\u00AC\u00B0<\\J\u00A11\u00C6,\u00CC\u0088\u00C1?8u\u00CE\u0099j\u00AD'a\u0087\x0F\u00F7\u00DEq\u00C6\u0093\u00B0\u00C3\u0087C\b\x14c<\t;k\u00D8\x18C;Yk\u00C9{?\r3\u009B\u00EF\u00ED\u00C3)\u00A5\u00D5\u00891\u00F3:\u008C/\u00C2\u00C3\u00B30\u00C3\u0084\u00F9\u00F1\u00E1\u00D6\u00DA\u00E9_\u008D\u009D\u00AF\u00C1\u00FC\x14VX\x0E~\x00i\u0096r%\u00B0\u00FF\x1E\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\u00AEB`\u0082"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should the image convert it to Base64.

Here are two threads here on stackoverflow about that option. At both I find the second answer more interesting.

[How can you encode to Base64 using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript#246813)

[JSON encode/decode base64 encode/decode in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665049/json-encode-decode-base64-encode-decode-in-javascript)

Comment: No there is an easier way. I just have to add a `toSource()` to the str variable. m( but thanks