# how to convert base64 encoded string to json string using angular js

Tags: javascript, java, css, angularjs, canvas

I have converted an image into a BASE64 encoded string ,
and then i need plz someone to explain howto convert it as json string,
and insert into DB

or else if any other ways is available to convert image as json string 
plz someone explain me

Comment: `convert image as json string` an image encoded to base64 gives you a string ... there's no reason to "convert" a string to JSON ... what key would you use for this object? or is it just a JSON encoded array? you only have a single string, no reason to stick it in an array - keep things simple - a base64 encoded image is fine to work with

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665049/json-encode-decode-base64-encode-decode-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

read [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript), you can use `btoa (encode)` and `atob(decode)` methods