# JS: How to generate (random ) ID like ItXaK9gw

Tags: javascript, uid

What is the best way to generate random (pseudo-unique) ID that will include: 1) small chars 2) cap chars 3) digits with JavaScript (browser and node).

I know the solution with small chars register.

```
return ("00000" + (Math.random()*Math.pow(36,idLength) << 0).toString(36)).substr(-idLength);
```

I wonder if there is a like straightforward solution for ItXaK9gw like IDs.

Comment: I know that random != uniq. I tried for example return ("00000" + (Math.random()*Math.pow(36,idLength) << 0).toString(36)).substr(-idLength); but there are only letters of one register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to already know how to generate a pseudo-random integer, so then all you need to do is [base64 encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774622/how-to-base64-encode-inside-of-javascript) it.

Be aware though that JavaScript's pseudo-random number generator is not [cryptographically strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) so an attacker who can run JS in the browser at the same time you're generating your ID may be able to guess with relatively high likelihood the number you generate.